# Portable USB Web Server: Alternative to Hosts file

Tags: webserver, portability, httpserver, portable-applications

I am looking for portable web servers (for PHP programming) to carry on my usb flash drive. But most importantly a portability that does not require access to the Hosts file. Writing on the hosts file requires administrative privileges, so if a "portable" web server tool still needs this file, then it's not really very portable.

Portability, for me, means that most times I'd be using computers that are not mine and on which I wouldn't have admin rights. The webservers I'd tried so far (eg: EasyPHP) are portable as far as being able to run from a usb flash disk, but still needs the hosts file.

So my question is: How can I setup an alternative Hosts file? like having one on my usb flash drive that my portable webserver can use? Or a portable webserver that is already implemented in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

[uniform server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) , it is portable and very stable. I am using it for production on some machines for years.

> Uniform Server ZeroXI releases are versions with pre-installed ZeroXI
>   modules producing a standard WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP)
>   server package. After extracting, servers are ready to run either from
>   a USB memory stick or PC. Apart from changing the MySQL password
>   (optional) there is no configuration required.